# I have a git branch called Tofazzal with perfectly working code, and I want to turn it into the main. I'm currently on the master branch

Tags: git, error-handling, git-branch

I am in the tofazzal branch (development) and I want to pull from the main branch (live site) and incorporate all the changes into my development branch. is there a better way to do this? here is what I had planned on doing, after committing changes:

```
git checkout main
git pull origin tofazzal
git merge
```

Comment: It is pointless to say `git merge` after `git pull`. `git pull` _is_ a merge.

Comment: "Better" in what way? Merging your branch into the main (or master) branch is usually how it's done, but some projects and organizations prefer a different workflow for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pull from the main branch (live site) and incorporate all the changes into my development branch

It's unclear what your goal is, but I *presume* you're saying you want to make your current branch `tofazzal` catch up with what `main` has been doing. In that case, stay on `tofazzal` and say:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/main
```